# Probability that they will enjoy exactly one of the two activities

Tags: probability

So the question looks like this
A survey finds that 30% of all Canadians enjoy jogging.  Of those Canadians who enjoy jogging, it is known that 40% of them enjoy swimming.  For the 70% of Canadians who do not enjoy jogging, it is known that 60% of them enjoy swimming.

Suppose a Canadian is randomly selected.  What is the probability that they enjoy exactly one of the two activities?  Select the answer closest to yours.

I solved this using 
$$
P(Jogging or Swimming)=P(Jogging) + P (Swimming) - P(Jogging and swimming)

P(Jogging)=0.3

P(Swimming)=0.54

P(Jogging and swimming)=0.12
$$

my answer was 0.72 but it was wrong. Please, what am I missing?

Comment: What values did you use for each?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that bit. I just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer calculates the probability that the selected person enjoys either swimming or jogging, and possibly both. The question is asking for the probability that the person enjoys exactly one of the activities, not both.

The probability of this is P(swimming or jogging) - P(swimming and jogging). So you should get $.72 - .12 = .6$

Answer (score 1):

The formula that you used is wrong. Let $J$ be P(jogging), $S$ be P(swimming).

$$J+S$$

measures P(Jogging and Swimming) twice, so to get rid of it completely we need to subtract twice P(jogging and swimming).

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply get events that people like jogging but do not like swimming and another event that people like swimming but do not like jogging.

Of the 30% who likes jogging, 40% likes swimming too thus, it can be implied that the remaining 60% do not like swimming: 0.30 * 0.60 = 0.18

Of the remaining 70% who do not like jogging, 60% of them likes swimming: 0.70 * 0.60 = 0.42

Add them together: 0.18 + 0.42 = 0.60

There is a 60% probability that the random person selected enjoy exactly one of the two activities.